# LDAP query to get only OUs having atleast one Group in it from Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Looking for LDAP query to get only those OUs from Active Directory having group in it.

most important is only using LDAP query, I don't want to filter each OU using C# code.

Thanks

Comment: ??? Any given group will only exist in just a single OU - is that what you're looking for?? Or do you want only those OU's that have at least one group inside them??? Not very clear.....

Comment: @marc_s only those OU's that have at least one group inside them

Answer (score 0):

Groups can be stored in organizationalUnits but also in domain, containers.

Using DirectoryEntry or AccountManagement you can do the following :

1. Find all the groups from the domain root
2. Foreach group add the container property to a list of OUs
3. Get unique entries from the list of OUs

---

Here is a solution using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` and `System.DirectoryServices`

```
/* Retreiving a principal context
 */
PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WM2008R2ENT:389", "dc=dom,dc=fr", "jpb", "PWD");

/* Look for all the groups from the root
 */
GroupPrincipal allGroups = new GroupPrincipal(domainContext);
allGroups.Name = "*";


/* Bind a searcher
 */
PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
searcher.QueryFilter = allGroups;
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> hRes = searcher.FindAll();

/* Read The result
 */
List<DirectoryEntry> listContainerWithGroups = new List<DirectoryEntry>();
foreach (GroupPrincipal grp in hRes)
{
  DirectoryEntry deGrp = grp.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
  if (deGrp != null)
    listContainerWithGroups.Add(deGrp.Parent);
}

/* Get Unique Entries
 */
var listContainerWithGroupsUnique = from o in listContainerWithGroups
                                    group o by o.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value into dePackets
                                    select dePackets.First();
foreach (DirectoryEntry deTmp in listContainerWithGroupsUnique)
{
  Console.WriteLine(deTmp.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with a single search. You'll need to grab each OU and then do a one-level search of that OU for (&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)). This is not going to be particuarly efficient when you consider how many searches you might need to perform. Also consider whether or not you need to handle the scenario where you have OU=A\OU=B. If OU=B includes the group, do you include OU=A (the parent)?